# Animation transition with React Native doesn't work properly

Tags: android, animation, react-native, react-animated

I'm playing with react Native and I have a problem with the animation of transition.

Windows 10 - Hyper V, Visual Code Emulator Android - Ignite Boilerplate.

**What I'm trying to do:**

When I click, I want to show a circle with a scale animation from 0 to 2 on the click position.

**What I have:**

See the picture below (I have put a setTimout to see the first frame). On the first click, The component is displayed a first time very quickly with its natural width and height but the scale on 0,001 has no effect. After that, the animation begins from the scale 0,001 to 2.

With the other clicks, The circle start the first frames with the dimension of the previous circle. and then, the animation begins. But one more time, the scale : 0 has no effect at the first frame.

[image: The start of the animation take the data of the last called component]

Here is the code of the Lunch screen:

```
export default class LaunchScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    clicks: []
  };
  handlePress(evt) {
    console.log(evt.nativeEvent.locationX, evt.nativeEvent.locationY)
    let xCoord = evt.nativeEvent.locationX;
    let yCoord = evt.nativeEvent.locationY;
    this
      .state
      .clicks
      .push({x: xCoord, y: yCoord});
    this.setState({clicks: this.state.clicks});
  }
  renderClick() {
    if (this.state.clicks.length > 0) {
      return this
        .state
        .clicks
        .map((item, i) =>< ClickAnimation key = {
          item.x
        }
        x = {
          item.x
        }
        y = {
          item.y
        } />)
    } else {
      return <View/>
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollView}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            style={styles.touchableWithoutFeedback}
            onPress=
            {evt => this.handlePress(evt)}>
            <View style={styles.scrollView}>
              {this.renderClick()}
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And here the component of the circle:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Animated, View, Easing} from 'react-native';

export default class ClickAnimation extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this.state)
        this.state = {
            scaleAnim: new Animated.Value(0.001);
        };  
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        Animated
            .timing(this.state.scaleAnim, {
            toValue: 2,
            duration: 2000
        })
            .start();
       .scaleAnim
    }
    render() {
        return (<Animated.View
            style={{
            zIndex: 10,
            borderColor: "blue",
            borderRadius: 400,
            borderWidth: 1,
            position: "absolute",
            top: this.props.y,
            left: this.props.x,
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            transform: [
                {
                    scaleY: this.state.scaleAnim
                        ? this.state.scaleAnim
                        : 0
                }, {
                    scaleX: this.state.scaleAnim
                        ? this.state.scaleAnim
                        : 0
                }
            ]
        }}/>);
    }
}
```

Do you have an Idea why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

This come with this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6278

I had seen it and this is why I wrote 0,001. But 0,001 is still to little. With 0,01 it works great.

**So the answer is:**

Just replace 0.001 by 0.01 because it was too little.